# Print numerals in order in a sine wave

Tags: java

**Background:**

I've successfully written code that generates a sine wave from 0 to 2pi. Adjusting the constants `xPrecision` and `yPrecision`, you can stretch the graph horizontally or vertically.

I gain this neat output (in Eclipse), when `xPrecision = yPrecision = 10`:

[image]

**My query:**

I now wish to display digits 0 to 9 instead of the stars. So, the leftmost star is replaced by 0, the second left-most star is replaced by 1, and so on. When you reach 9, the next digit is again zero.

I am clueless as to how to do this. I have looked at wave patterns [like this](https://javasimplify.blogspot.com/2017/11/top-5-different-wave-pattern-programs-in-java.html), but they are fixed width patterns, while mine is scalable.

The only way I can think of is converting my output to a 2D character array, then scraping the `*`s manually from left to right, and replacing them with the digits, and then printing it. However, this is extremely memory consuming at bigger values of `x/yPrecision`.

> What is the most optimized way to achieve this output?

---

**Code to print sine wave:**

```
class sine {
  static final double xPrecision = 10.0; // (1/xPrecision) is the precision on x-values
  static final double yPrecision = 10.0; // (1/yPrecision) is the precision on y-values
  static final int PI = (int) (3.1415 * xPrecision);
  static final int TPI = 2 * PI; // twice PI
  static final int HPI = PI / 2; // half PI

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    double xd;

    for(int start = (int) (1 * yPrecision), y = start; y >= -start; y--){       
      double x0 = Math.asin(y / yPrecision),
            x1 = bringXValueWithinPrecision(x0),
            x2 = bringXValueWithinPrecision(x0 + TPI / xPrecision),
            x3 = bringXValueWithinPrecision(PI/xPrecision - x0);

      // for debug
      //System.out.println(y + " " + x0 + " " + x1 + " " + x2 + " " + x3);

      for(int x = 0; x <= TPI; x++){
        xd = (x / xPrecision);

        if(x1 == xd || x2 == xd || x3 == xd)
          System.out.print("*");
        else System.out.print(" ");      
      }

      System.out.println();
    }
  }

  public static double bringXValueWithinPrecision(double num){
      // obviously num has 16 floating points
      // we need to get num within our precision
      return Math.round(num * xPrecision) / xPrecision;
  }
}
```

Comment: Will your code always print a perfect sine? If so then when you get to `**`, two consecutive asterisks, this is when you have all your sine, right? First part (out of 4) `/`, you invert this to `\\`` to get the second part and then you invert `/\\` to `\\/` to get the second half. *(Seems there is a bug with \\ character in the comments)*

Comment: @Adelin I understand your point. Though I am not sure how this solves my current problem. (*yeah it's buggy `\\\`*)

Comment: I just added an answer with the usage of it

Comment: @Adelin Ok looking

Answer (score 7):

"Draw" the graph in memory first, then assign digits to its vertical points, and print them in a separate pass.

```
               01                                              
           9        2                                          
         8            3                                        
        7              4                                       
      6                  5                                     
     5                    6                                    
    4                      7                                   
   3                        8                                  
  2                          9                                 
 1                            0                                
0                              1                              2
                                2                            1 
                                 3                          0  
                                  4                        9   
                                   5                      8    
                                    6                    7     
                                     7                  6      
                                       8              5        
                                        9            4         
                                          0        3           
                                              12
```

See comments in the code for an explanation of how this works:

```
static final double xPrecision = 10.0; // (1/xPrecision) is the precision on x-values
static final double yPrecision = 10.0; // (1/yPrecision) is the precision on y-values
static final int PI = (int) (3.1415 * xPrecision);
static final int TPI = 2 * PI; // twice PI
static final int HPI = PI / 2; // half PI

public static void main(String[] args) {
    // This part is the same as OP's code, except that instead of printing '*'
    // it stores the corresponding row number in the array of rows
    double xd;
    int[] row = new int[100];
    Arrays.fill(row, -1);
    int r = 0;
    int maxc = 0; // Mark the rightmost column of all iterations
    for(int start = (int) (1 * yPrecision), y = start; y >= -start; y--){       
      double x0 = Math.asin(y / yPrecision),
            x1 = bringXValueWithinPrecision(x0),
            x2 = bringXValueWithinPrecision(x0 + TPI / xPrecision),
            x3 = bringXValueWithinPrecision(PI/xPrecision - x0);
      int c = 0;
      for(int x = 0; x <= TPI; x++, c++){
        xd = (x / xPrecision);
        // This is where the asterisk used to go
        if(x1 == xd || x2 == xd || x3 == xd)
          row[c] = r;
      }
      maxc = Math.max(c, maxc);
      r++;
    }
    // Walk the assigned rows, and give each one a consecutive digit
    int[] digit = new int[100];
    int current = 0;
    for (int i = 0 ; i != 100 ; i++) {
        if (row[i] != -1) {
            digit[i] = (current++) % 10;
        }
    }
    // Now walk the rows again, this time printing the pre-assigned digits
    for (int i = 0 ; i != r ; i++) {
        for (int c = 0 ; c != maxc ; c++) {
            if (row[c] == i) {
                System.out.print(digit[c]);
            } else {
                System.out.print(' ');
            }
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
}

public static double bringXValueWithinPrecision(double num){
      // obviously num has 16 floating points
      // we need to get num within our precision
      return Math.round(num * xPrecision) / xPrecision;
}
```

The first part of the code fills `row[i]` array, which contains row for the asterisk in column `i`. First few numbers from `row[]` array would look like this:

```
10 9 8 7 6 5 4 - 3 2 - 1 - - - 0 0 - - - 1 - 2 3 - 4 5 6 7 8 9 10
```

`-` denotes cells with `-1`, which represents a missing value. The array says that the left-most asterisk is on row 10, the next asterisk is on row 9, then 8, 7, 6, and so on. Asterisks 11 and 12 are on row zero, which is at the top.

The second loop walks `rows`, skips `-1`s, and assign consecutive digits to all non-negative positions.

The third loop walks the entire field again going row-by-row, printing values from pre-assigned `digit[]` array when the current row matches the value in the `row[]` array.

[Demo.](https://ideone.com/xCu88Q)

Comment: Mind explaining a bit more about the role of `maxc`?

Comment: @GaurangTandon That's the rightmost column that we've ever reached. Do you understand the meaning of `row[]` and `digit[]` arrays?

Comment: I am trying to, but I can't. Can you write a short step-wise working of your code, in bullet points? Thanks!

Comment: Why did you initialize your `row` array to a default size of `100`? Is that because it's just a number `>` the total number of `*`s printed, or some other reason?

Comment: Value at `0π` is `0`, at `π` is `1` and at `2π` it becomes 2. There is something that is not working right. All the values at `0π`, `π` and `2π` should be `0`.

Answer (score 5):

If you replace:

```
System.out.print("*");
```

with

```
System.out.print(""+(x%10));
```

it seems to **nearly** work.

```
               56                                              
           1        0                                          
         9            2                                        
        8              3                                       
      6                  5                                     
     5                    6                                    
    4                      7                                   
   3                        8                                  
  2                          9                                 
 1                            0                                
0                              1                              2
                                2                            1 
                                 3                          0  
                                  4                        9   
                                   5                      8    
                                    6                    7     
                                     7                  6      
                                       9              4        
                                        0            3         
                                          2        1           
                                              67
```

Perhaps some further adjustments might get it perfect.

Comment: This skips digits where the column has no asterisk.

Comment: shouldn't topmost `156` be `012`?

Comment: It is very intuitive to take modulo of `x`, since that's the only thing increasing horizontally, so +1, but as dasblinkenlight points out, it skips some digits :(

Answer (score 2):

Doing it in a completely different way produces a different picture but achieves your effect.

Essentially,

```
for each y
  for each x
    calculate fx = sin(x)
    if fx == y print * else print space
```

It's very inefficient as it calculates `sin(x)` `x*y` times when, if you filled a matrix, you could calculate `sin(x)` just `x` times.

```
static final double xPrecision = 10.0; // (1/xPrecision) is the precision on x-values
static final double yPrecision = 10.0; // (1/yPrecision) is the precision on y-values

private void sine() {
    for (double y = 1; y >= -1; y -= 1.0 / yPrecision) {
        int n = 0;
        for (double x = 0; x < 2.0 * Math.PI; x += 1.0 / xPrecision, n++) {
            double fx = Math.sin(x);
            boolean star = Math.round(fx*xPrecision) == Math.round(y*yPrecision);
            System.out.print((star ? ""+(n%10) : " "));
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
}

public void test(String[] args) {
    sine();
}
```

Gives you:

```
             345678                                            
           12      901                                         
         90           2                                        
        8              34                                      
      67                 5                                     
     5                    6                                    
    4                      7                                   
   3                        8                                  
  2                          9                                 
 1                            0                                
0                              1                               
                                2                             2
                                 3                           1 
                                  4                         0  
                                   56                      9   
                                     7                    8    
                                      8                 67     
                                       9               5       
                                        01           34        
                                          23       12          
                                            4567890
```

Comment: (+1) for alternative approach without arrays! :D Sidenote: having to calculate `sin x` for each `x` and comparing it with `y` (this code), instead of computing `asin y` once and then comparing it with each x (my original code), is much more inefficient imo. Please see if you can get around this limitation in your original answer. Although it's still good :)

Answer (score 1):

Here's my solution, which basically uses the half of the sine in 4 for loops:

- from half to 0
- from 0 to half
- from half to the end
- from the end to the half

And in each loop replace only the first asterisk.

```
class sine {
    static final double xPrecision = 14.0; // (1/xPrecision) is the precision on x-values
    static final double yPrecision = 14.0; // (1/yPrecision) is the precision on y-values
    static final int PI = (int)(3.1415 * xPrecision);
    static final int TPI = 2 * PI; // twice PI
    static final int HPI = PI / 2; // half PI

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        double xd;
        String str = "";
        for (int start = (int)(1 * yPrecision), y = start; y >= -start; y--) {
            double x0 = Math.asin(y / yPrecision),
                x1 = bringXValueWithinPrecision(x0),
                x2 = bringXValueWithinPrecision(x0 + TPI / xPrecision),
                x3 = bringXValueWithinPrecision(PI / xPrecision - x0);

            // for debug
            //System.out.println(y + " " + x0 + " " + x1 + " " + x2 + " " + x3);

            for (int x = 0; x <= TPI; x++) {
                xd = (x / xPrecision);

                if (x1 == xd || x2 == xd || x3 == xd)
                    str += "*";
                else str += " ";
            }
            str += "\n";
        }
        String[] rows = str.split("\n");
        int half = (int)(1 * yPrecision);

        // we use this half in for loops, from half to 0, from 0 to half, from half to the end and from the end to the half, and replace only the first asterisk.
        int val = 0;
        for (int i = half; i >= 0; i--) {
            if (val == 10) val = 0;
            rows[i] = rows[i].replaceFirst("\\*", Integer.toString(val++));
        }
        for (int i = 0; i <= half; i++) {
            if (val == 10) val = 0;


            rows[i] = rows[i].replaceFirst("\\*", Integer.toString(val++));
        }
        for (int i = half + 1; i < rows.length; i++) {
            if (val == 10) val = 0;
            rows[i] = rows[i].replaceFirst("\\*", Integer.toString(val++));
        }
        for (int i = rows.length - 1; i >= half; i--) {
            if (val == 10) val = 0;
            rows[i] = rows[i].replaceFirst("\\*", Integer.toString(val++));
        }

        System.out.println(String.join("\n", rows));
    }

    public static double bringXValueWithinPrecision(double num) {
        // obviously num has 16 floating points
        // we need to get num within our precision
        return Math.round(num * xPrecision) / xPrecision;
    }
}
```

Result:

```
               01                                              
           9        2                                          
         8            3                                        
        7              4                                       
      6                  5                                     
     5                    6                                    
    4                      7                                   
   3                        8                                  
  2                          9                                 
 1                            0                                
0                              1                              2
                                2                            1 
                                 3                          0  
                                  4                        9   
                                   5                      8    
                                    6                    7     
                                     7                  6      
                                       8              5        
                                        9            4         
                                          0        3           
                                              12
```

Comment: Wrt "finds the half of the sine" won't the half of the sine wave always be at (start + 1)th row from the top? (Since the y-values range from start to -start (both inclusive)...)

Comment: That's correct (although not `start + 1` but `start`). I didn't really look into how exactly the whole sine is created. I only replaced the direct print with a `str` creation and went from there. But indeed, you can skip the code that gets the half

Comment: I understand what you're doing here, +1 for alternative approach, but I am looking for a non-array based approach. Moreover, this code will falter if I extend the sine wave till 4pi or 8pi. We will need to add more `for` loops :(

Comment: @GaurangTandon Your code (in the question statement) doesn't scale very well to longer periods either. Why didn't you state that requirement explicitly?

Comment: @DavidK if I take the modulo of `x` value with `TPI`, I can easily extend my graph till any `2npi`. And I was only pointing out a small fault with this code, I never said this was an absolute requirement.

Comment: Well that can be optimized. You give it a `startLocation`, and `up` or `down` `direction`, and loop endlessly in that direction `while(str.contains("*"))`, alternating the direction

Comment: @Adelin Yes, I understand now. It can be optimized.

Answer (score 1):

By using the fact that each row has one point (on each slope), you can calculate which digit to display at each point without using extra memory or loops.  Here's my example.  Note that I only checked that this example only works if `xPrecision` and `yPrecision` are integers.  You'll have to modify it if you want to use doubles.

```
class sine {
    static final double xPrecision = 10.0; // (1/xPrecision) is the precision on x-values
    static final double yPrecision = 10.0; // (1/yPrecision) is the precision on y-values
    static final int PI = (int) Math.round(Math.PI * xPrecision);
    static final int TPI = 2 * PI; // twice PI
    static final int HPI = PI / 2; // half PI
    static final int cycles = 2; // prints from x=0 to 2*cycles*pi

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        double xd;
        int cycleoffset, cycleoffset2, topbottomoffset = 1;

        for (int start = (int) (1 * yPrecision), y = start; y >= -start; y--) {
            double x0 = Math.asin(y / yPrecision), x1 = bringXValueWithinPrecision(x0),
                    x2 = bringXValueWithinPrecision(x0 + TPI / xPrecision),
                    x3 = bringXValueWithinPrecision(PI / xPrecision - x0), tmp;

            if (y == start) {
                if (x1 == x3) // when there is only one point at the top/bottom
                    topbottomoffset = 0;
                else if (x1 > x3) // swap x1 and x3
                {
                    tmp = x1;
                    x1 = x3;
                    x3 = tmp;
                }
            } else if (y == -start) {
                // I don't think this is needed, but just for safety make sure there is only one point on the bottom if there was only one point at the top
                if (topbottomoffset == 0)
                    x2 = x3;
                else if (x2 < x3) // swap x2 and x3
                {
                    tmp = x2;
                    x2 = x3;
                    x3 = tmp;
                }
            }

            cycleoffset = (int) (4 * yPrecision + 2 * topbottomoffset);
            cycleoffset2 = -cycleoffset;

            int start1 = topbottomoffset + 2 * (int) yPrecision, start2 = 2 * topbottomoffset + 4 * (int) yPrecision;

            for (int x = 0, lim = cycles * TPI; x <= lim; x++) {
                xd = ((x % TPI) / xPrecision);
                if (x % TPI == 0)
                    cycleoffset2 += cycleoffset;

                // x = 0 to pi/2
                if (x1 == xd)
                    System.out.print((cycleoffset2 + y) % 10);
                // x = 3pi/2 to 2pi
                else if (x2 == xd)
                    System.out.print((cycleoffset2 + start2 + y) % 10);
                // x = pi/2 to 3pi/2
                else if (x3 == xd)
                    System.out.print((cycleoffset2 + start1 - y) % 10);
                else
                    System.out.print(" ");
            }

            System.out.println();
        }
    }

    public static double bringXValueWithinPrecision(double num) {
        // obviously num has 16 floating points
        // we need to get num within our precision
        return Math.round(num * xPrecision) / xPrecision;
    }
}
```

**EDIT**
The digits for the different ranges are calculated as follows

0 < x < π/2 : This one is simplest since it is the first range.  Since the middle row is y=0 and that is where the sine wave starts, we can just use `y` to find the digit.

π/2 < x < 3π/2 : The digits here count up as we go down, but `y` decreases as we go down.  So we have to use a `-y` term.  On the top row, `y=yPrecision`, and the last digit from the previous range was `yPrecision`.  So we use `2*yPrecision - y`, because that includes the `-y`, and is equal to yPrecision at the first term (where y=yPrecision).

3π/2 < x < 2π : The digits here count down as we go down, so we need a `+y` term, but the tricky part is figuring where to start.  Since the sine wave by this point has gone from 0 to yPrecision to 0 to -yPrecision, the bottom point (x=3π/2) should start at 3*yPrecision.  Since y=-yPrecision at the bottom point, we use `4*yPrecision + y`, since that includes a `+y` and is equal to 3*yPrecision at the first term (where y=-yPrecision).

The `topbottomoffset` term : Depending on the values used for xPrecision and yPrecision, there can be one or two points plotted on the top and bottom rows.  If there are two points, we need to add one to digits in the π/2 to 3π/2 range, and two to the digits in the 3π/2 to 2π range.

The `cycleoffset` term : If multiple cycles of the sine wave are plotted, additional cycles need to start from the last digit used in the previous cycle.  Each cycle goes from 0 to yPrecision to 0 to -yPrecision to 0, which is equal to 4*yPrecision.  So each new cycle needs to start at 4*yPrecision*[the number of previous cycles].  If there are two points on the top and bottom rows, those need to be factored in as well.

Swapping values: When there are two points on the top row, then `x1>x3`. This happens because when `y=yPrecision`, we're taking `Math.asin(1)`, which happens to be exactly `pi/2=1.5707963267948966` in Java's double system. On lower `xPrecision` (`<100.0`), the rounding done by `bringXValueWithinPrecision` brings `x1` up to `1.58` while `x3` down to nearly `1.56`. Hence, they need to be swapped in order to get the correct numerical order.

Comment: I ran your code even when integral `xPrecision` does not equal `yPrecision`, and it works pretty well! Wow! Now let me try to understand it...

Comment: I managed to scale your code for more than one cycle of `0` to `2pi`, so I added that in your post. Please see if it alright with you. Also, I do not understand you arrived at that expression `(2 * offset + 4 * yPrecision + y) % 10);` and the one below it. Please explain a bit more. Thank you!

Comment: The multiple waves display correctly, but I added a cycleoffset to account for starting at different digits on additional cycles.  I also tried to write some explanations.  Hope it helps!

Comment: I am still fiddling with your code. I figured out the problem in your last part and added an explanation it. My main problem with the current code is that it's doing so many computations even in one iteration of `x` that it doesn't justify simply taking `Math.sin(x)` instead, as [done above](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48210141/2675672). I added some optimizations. But am still trying more...

Comment: I was able to bring down the successive calculations to just a modulo operation. Have a look!

Answer (score 1):

Since this is Java, how about let's actually use some objects *as objects* rather than just as places to define a couple of functions.

Treat your wavy graph as if it is a composition of several different "branches" of the inverse sine function. (Mathematically, that's how we explain the way your version of the program uses `Math.asin` to produce multiple coordinates for stars.) 
Branch 0 is the initial rising part of the curve,
Branch 1 is the falling part of the curve after Branch 0,
Branch 2 is the rising part of the curve after Branch 1, and so forth.
The branches cross the middle line of the output at x values 0,
PI, 2*PI, 3*PI, and so forth.
Depending on how far you want the graph to extend to the right, it is easy to determine how many branches you need.
For example, to plot from 0 to 8*PI you need nine branches
(Branch 0, Branch 8, and the seven branches between those two).

You can implement each branch using an object of some class,
let's call it `ArcSineBranch`.
It has a constructor, `ArcSineBranch(int)`, that takes the branch number as a parameter.
Create some sort of ordered list (which could just be an `ArcSineBranch[]` array) and put these branch objects in it,
making sure the branch numbers go in sequence from 0 up to the largest number needed.

You'll also want to implement some way to tell the first `ArcSineBranch` where its leftmost end is--in the example in the question, the leftmost end of first branch is at `y == 0`, whereas for all other rising branches it is at `y == -start` and for all falling branches it is at `y == start`.

Now you call a mutator function of the first `ArcSineBranch` that tells it its leftmost symbol is `0`. Treat this as an integer (rather than a string) for now to make the arithmetic easier.
You then query the first `ArcSineBranch` for the rightmost symbol it will write, which it can compute from the leftmost symbol and the number of lines it will write symbols on.
You also query it for the x coordinate of that rightmost symbol.
(The object computes the x-coordinate of the symbol for any y-coordinate by either adding or subtracting a rounded multiple of `Math.asin(y / yPrecision)` from a multiple of `PI`.)

Now for each `ArcSineBranch` in the list, you pass to it the rightmost symbol and x coordinate written by the previous branch.
This `ArcSineBranch` uses that information to determine the leftmost symbol it writes and the y coordinate of that symbol.
(I am being careful here about the y coordinate in case you choose a value of `xPrecision` that causes the rightmost x coordinate of one branch to be the same as the leftmost x coordinate of the next; we should only write one symbol at that place in the output, so we want the later branch to skip its leftmost x coordinate and write its leftmost symbol in the next place, one line up or down. But if the x coordinates are different we want the later branch to write a symbol on the same line.)

Now that the later `ArcSineBranch` "knows" the leftmost symbol it will print and thata symbol's y coordinate, you can query it for its rightmost symbol and x coordinate, and pass those to the next `ArcSineBranch`, and so forth.

Once you have traversed all the `ArcSineBranch` objects in this way,
so that each object knows what symbols need to be written for its branch and where to write them, you can loop `for (y = start; y >= -start; y--)`;
within that loop you loop over the list of `ArcSineBranch` objects;
for each object you query whether it requires a symbol to be written at 
y-coordinate `y`.
If the object requires a symbol to be written,
you query which symbol to write at which x-coordinate,
then space the output to the right until you reach that x-coordinate and write that symbol there.
But of course, first check that this would not plot a symbol beyond the
right-hand edge of the desired graph. 
(This check really only applies to the last `ArcSineBranch`, so you can optimize the code a bit by looping over the other branches first and then dealing with the last `ArcSineBranch` separately.)

I've already described this algorithm in more detail than I initially wanted to. There should be enough information here to code this into Java in a relatively straightforward way, though there are still some localized details to be worked out.

---

Note that the design in this answer is intended to use the same mathematical ideas as the code in the question uses to decide where to plot the points.
Specifically, `ArcSineBranch(0)` produces the `x1` values from the original code, `ArcSineBranch(1)` produces the `x3` values, and `ArcSineBranch(2)` produces the `x2` values.
The implementation of this design should plot a digit at the location of each star plotted by the original code, and should plot no other digits.

Comment: (+1) This does use an array, but not to store the entire pattern strings, but instead objects which store coordinates of the values where we print numbers. I'll try write this out and then get back to you.

Comment: Btw, my code does print a *sine* branch (as I am taking `asin(y)` not `asin(x)`). So I am not sure why you should think it is an *arcsine* branch instead.

Comment: I say "arc sine" because that's the full mathematical-English name of `Math.asin`: the "a" before "sin" stands for "arc". So your original code is based on the "arc sine" function, which is important because that's how you get one star per line on each upward or downward piece of the curve. That was very clever of you. As we can see, when people try to use the sine function directly to plot the digits on the curve, they tend to get multiple consecutive digits at one y value during the rising and falling parts of the plot, not just on the top or bottom lines.

Comment: Yes, thanks :) Though, what I was trying to point out to you is that the curve I have plotted is `y=sin(x)`, so each branch of the curve is actually a `SineBranch`, as opposed to an `ArcSineBranch` as you've named it.

Comment: In mathematics-speak, the word "branch" is used as a modifier of inverse functions: one says "a branch of the arc sine function" or "a branch of the complex logarithm". I don't think I've ever seen the words "a branch of the sine function" in mathematical writing. But you're right, what we are plotting are the various upward and downward segments of a _sine_ function. not an arc sine. So `ArcSineBranch` is merely a part of the _implementation_ of the program; it does not describe the _output._ We turn branches of the arc sine into segments of the sine function by plotting them "sideways".

Comment: So it's "ArcSine" because we use `Math.asin`, and "Branch" because we need the `x2` and `x3` values, not just `x1`.

Comment: "In mathematics-speak, the word "branch" is used as a modifier of inverse functions: one says "a branch of the arc sine function" or "a branch of the complex logarithm" Ok, I dd not know that. Thanks for clarifying in detail :D

Answer (score 1):

Care about a different approach?

```
                                            3030              
                                          28    28            
                                        26        26          

                                      22            22        

                                    18                18      


                                  12                    12    


                                06                        06  


00                            00                            00


  06                        06                                


    12                    12                                  


      18                18                                    

        22            22                                      

          26        26                                        
            28    28                                          
              3030
```

Solution:

```
import static java.lang.Math.sin;
import static java.lang.Math.PI;
import static java.lang.Math.abs;

public class Sine {

    static final Integer points = 30; // points on x and y axis

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        // contains graph points
        Boolean[][] graph = new Boolean[points + 1][points + 1];

        for (Double x = 0.0; x <= points; x++) {
            // x axis pi value
            Double pi = (x / points) * 2 * PI;
            // sin(x) plot for x
            Integer sinx = (int) Math.round((sin(pi) * points / 2) + points / 2);
            graph[sinx][x.intValue()] = true;
        }

        for (Integer i = 0; i <= points; i++) {
            for (Integer j = 0; j <= points; j++) {

                // space characters on x axis
                Integer pt = (int) Math.floor(Math.log10(points) + 1);
                String space = String.format("%" + pt + "s", " ");

                // padding for p
                String p = String.format("%0" + (pt) + "d", abs(i - points / 2) * 2);

                System.out.print(graph[i][j] != null ? p : space);
            }
            System.out.println();
        }

    }

}
```

Approach:

- `points` contains the number of characters on x and y axis.
- `graph` contains `true` or `null` for each x and y characters.
- 1st for loop:

  1. Since the value of x in sine graph is from `0 to 2π`, we need to convert x accordingly. So `pi` contains the value of the same range but according to `x`.
  2. `sinx` is the `Integer` value according to `x`.
  3. No need to explain `graph[sinx][x.intValue()] = true;`.
- 2nd for loops:

  - 1st for loop

    - Execute LOOPLABEL.
    - Break to next line at the end.
  - 2nd for loop(LOOPLABEL)

    - `pt` holds the number for padding on y axis.
    - `space` is the space characters to be printed on y axis.
    - `p` is the converted range between 0 to `points`.
    - Printing `graph[i][j]`

**[DEMO](https://ideone.com/LzC64m)**

Comment: Seems really cool! :D But I wonder what pattern are you printing? "00,06,12,18,22,26,28,30" What pattern is that ?

Comment: @GaurangTandon Its the range of `points` Integer. In your case, it will be `xPrecision` and `yPrecision`

Comment: @GaurangTandon The graph was not printing completely. Updated!

Comment: On a curious note though, why did you import those three classes from `java.lang`? Were they added by your IDE by default? Because, I don't see any reason in importing them as they're always present by default... And also, why are you using wrapper classes for the primitive data types? :-O

Comment: @GaurangTandon Check the import statements, those are static imports. Basically when you static import a method, you don't need to use fully qualified name to invoke them. Now coming to the next question, primitives does not support methods like `intValue()` and can not have `null`. There could be three possible values of `Boolean` while `boolean` will have only two of them. Frankly speaking, I hate the color that is displayed in my ide for primitives :p

Comment: What you just told comes only from long experience in java coding, and I learnt new things today, so kudos! :D I will try understand your code with fresh energy now!

Comment: @GaurangTandon Sure, get back when you need to know something about my code :)

Answer (score -2):

Add a counter in your loop and reset it when 9 is reached:

```
for(int x = 0, counter = 0; x <= TPI; x++, counter++){
    xd = (x / xPrecision);

    if(x1 == xd || x2 == xd || x3 == xd) {
      System.out.print("" + counter);

      if (counter == 9) {
          counter = 0;
      }
    } else {
        System.out.print(" ");      
    }
}
```

Comment: He prints line-by-line, so the top of the sine would read `0 1`, then `2   3` on the next line, and so on.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight Exactly, that's the problem I'm facing! This code will print the topmost `*` as 0, then second topmost as `1`. Instead of going left to right, this is going top to bottom. But anyway, thanks for your attempt Georg :)